# Find array subset with the maximum product

Tags: python, python-2.7

I received interview question to find the non-empty subset of an array with the maximum product. I solved the task but one test out of five doesn't pass. I don't understand what I may have missed in my solution. (The task should be done in python 2.7)

Task is here:

I have an array of integers and I need to return the non-empty subset of elements with the maximum product of values. If I have an odd number of negative numbers in the array, I have to exclude one of them to make the selected product be positive.

If I have 0 inside, in general I'll want to exclude it, also. For example: for [2, 5, -2] result should be 10, for [-2,-5,-1, 0, 2] result should be 20.

I tried different edge cases like [-1], [1], [0], [0,0,0]

Solution is here:

```
from functools import reduce

def answer(arr):
    selection = [n for n in arr if n !=0 and -1000<=n<=1000]
    negative = [n for n in selection if n<0]
    if len(negative) % 2 == 1:
        selection.remove(max(negative))
    if not selection:
        return '0'
    else:
        return str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, selection))
```

Comment: You have an interview question for Python 2?  In 2020?

Comment: https://pythonclock.org python 2 already retired!

Comment: @StephenRauch yep, it is true)

Comment: Was the interview with Matt Parker (of numberphile)?

Comment: This is actually part of [Google's foo.bar challenge](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-foobar-challenge-googles-hidden-test-for-developers-ed8027c1184/), and yes, for some reason they run the test cases against Python 2.7.

Comment: @idjaw, @StephenRauch I get the same result with and without `1- 50` `-1000 - 1000` conditions. One test always fails. I thought that some edge cases were missed

Comment: @JohnPix Yes. I got this challenge too and I managed to get it without those conditions. Here's a couple of hints. Split positive and negative collections. Check for different conditions like empty, no negatives, no positives. It might be one of those types of edge cases. Try to pass different inputs to your code along the lines of `[]`, `[0]`, `[-1]`, `[-3, -5, -5]`, `[1,2,3]`, `[2]`. See what happens with your code. You should be able to handle those conditions.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107461/google-foobar-power-hungry?rq=1) is the same question done in java. It might help. Another  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525299/google-foobar-challenge-power-hungry-failing-test-no-3-hidden-out-of-5-test?rq=1) but in Python.

Comment: Please note that your big edit to the question essentially rendered the answer impossible to understand, since the point that you missed in your original code is that you need to return the product of **at least one element in the input array**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A careful reading of the question indicates that `answer([-5])` should yield solution -5, since it needs to select a non-empty subset of the input array. However, your code returns 0 for `answer([-5])`. So perhaps something like:

```
from functools import reduce

def answer(arr):
    hasZero = any([n == 0 for n in arr])
    selection = [n for n in arr if n !=0 and -1000<=n<=1000]
    negative = [n for n in selection if n<0]
    if len(negative) % 2 == 1 and (len(selection) > 1 or hasZero):
        selection.remove(max(negative))
    if not selection:
        return '0'
    else:
        return str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, selection))

answer([-5])
# '-5'
answer([0, -5])
# '0'
```